# Turn Off Scientific Notation In Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, scientific-notation

In gnuplot I've enabled logscale for my `y` axis, which gives me `1` to `1,000,000`. However, the `1,000,000` tick appears in scientific notation. That stands out since its the only number in that form. I'd like to have it written as `1000000`. All of my Google searches for disabling scientific notation, formatting as a decimal, or making the ytics space wider haven't produced anything that solves my problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The format of the axis tics is set either with `set format x` or `set xtics format` (equivalent commands for `y`, `z`, `x2`, `y2` and `cb` exists as well).

Use `show format` to find out, which is the default format (result for 4.6.6, since 5.0 the default is `% h`)

```
gnuplot> show format
    tic format is: 
      x-axis: "% g"
      ...
```

`%g` is a gnuplot-specific format specifier, but works similar to the C format specifiers used for `sprintf` and similar functions. The definition of `%g` according to the gnuplot documentation is: "the shorter of `%e` and `%f`". This is why the format can change for a single axis.

So, finally, to change to a fixed format for all tics, use e.g.

```
set format y '%.0f'
```

Comment: Beautiful! That is exactly what I was looking for!