# Define and use vector for graph ticks

Tags: gnuplot, post-processing

I like to store everything I can in a variable since each gnuplot script I make generates tens of plots at once and it makes things easier to track. Here is a sample of one plot (variable of interest: `ytics`):

```
# Setup style
set terminal pngcairo dashed
unset key
set style line 1 pointtype 7 pointsize 0.3 linecolor rgb "black"

# Setup the plots' ytics
ytics_H2 = (0,0.002,0.004,0.006,0.008,0.010,0.012);

# Store the range for each variable
min_T  = 200; max_T  = 1800;
min_H2 = 0;   max_H2 = 0.012;



# Plot
set output 'my_output_H2.png'
set ytics ytics_H2
set xrange [min_T :max_T ]
set yrange [min_H2:max_H2]
plot 'scatter.dat' using 1:2 with points linestyle 1
```

Here is the result:
[image]

As you can see, only the last tick gets printed. If I replace the variable `ytics` by the vector to which it is set to, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such use cases gnuplot has macros:

```
set macros # necessary only for v < 5.0
ytics = "(1, 5, 8)"
set ytics @ytics
plot x
```

[image: Script output with gnuplot 5.0]

In order to use macros, you must define a string variable which contains the command parts you want to use at a later point, here `ytics = "(1, 5, 8)"`. Later you can use its content with `@ytics`.

The important fact here is, that gnuplot first replaces `@ytics` with the content of the string variable `ytics`, i.e. expands `set ytics @ytics` to `set ytics (1, 5, 5)` and only then executes the whole command.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed my issue. Another question: how I can force my tics to be written in the decimal form, say with 3 numbers past the decimal points?

Comment: See [Turn Off Scientific Notation In Gnuplot](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33245426/2604213) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Because your intervals are fixed and the same, you could also use `start, incr, end` form:

```
set ytic 0, 0.002, 0.012
```