# gnuplot converting time to scientific notation

Tags: gnuplot, scientific-notation

I have this program that grabs a lot of usage details regarding your computer and plots everything on a nice graph (below). The issue I am running into is that in the bottom left corner of the gnuplot window where it would normally report where on the (x,y) axis your mouse is currently at, it is reporting my x-axis in scientific notation.

For example, instead of stating that my mouse is at (33:10,20%) it is reporting that it is as (5.10770e+08,20%) <--**Random scientific notation**). I have already set the `timefmt` and `xdata`, so I am confused at to what I am missing in order to properly report the data. If someone could please help it would be greatly appreciated.

I have searched on superuser and Unix/Linux, and this question seems to fit on Stackoverflow the best as gnuplot has its own scripting language. Also if you look at the **gnuplot** tag on the various sites, **gnuplot** fits more on stackoverflow and has thousands of more tags compared to 30 and 67.

I have also viewed [Turn Off Scientific Notation In Gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33241104/turn-off-scientific-notation-in-gnuplot) and tried to implement the answer here (Christoph is the GNUPLOT man!), but have thus far been unable to configure it to work properly (it still displays the scientific notation).

```
gnuplot -e persist "set title 'Resource monitor' ; set timefmt '%y/%m/%d-%H:%M:%S' ; set xdata time ; set xlabel 'TIME' ; set ylabel 'PERCENT' set yrange [0:101]" -e "plot '${cpuResFile}' using 1:2 title 'CPU' smooth Bezier, '${memResFile}' using 1:2 title 'MEM' smooth Bezier ; pause -1"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're in the right place to ask for gnuplot help!

I've tried this on `x11` and `wxt`, don't know other interactive terminals.

You can switch between different mouse statusbar formats by pressing `1` (`2` cycle backwards)

Fore more help on interactivity, press `h` and you'll get a list ho keyboard shortcuts

Some information is on `help mouse format`

To change it programmatically with the corresponding command `set mouse format` (but I didn't manage to display properly date/time...)

Comment: I just re-read the doc. `set mouse mouseformat` is used for formatting the text on Button1 and Button2  actions -- copying the coordinates to the clipboard and temporarily annotating the mouse position. For the display-statusbar you have `set mouse format` (I changed my answer accordingly)

Comment: Thank you very much! That works perfectly. I included that portion of being the "right" site, as the past couple gnuplot questions I have asked have been closed stating "gnuplot" doesn't fit stackoverflow and have had multiple discussions that it does indeed. Thank you for the answer, that worked out perfectly!